# textarea becomes empty if I select an option from select input in a form why so?

Tags: html, select, textarea

I have a form where there are select  and textarea fields if I change the value ( select an option) in select. then textarea goes empty. why so? google doesn't have this answer..

Comment: please paste your form code

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks I got resolved my problem by putting textarea element inside paragraph. So that the select and textarea not remain in siblings relationship .